# When should connection.close() be invoked in a j2ee project?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I didn't use any framework since it's only a little project. Now I invoke `connection.close()` in the `destroy()` method of the main servlet. But there are some problems.

1. I don't know when `servlet.destroy()` is invoked...I thought when the browser is closed is the time it's invoked,but it seems wrong.
2. I found out that if I don't operate the page visiting my project,after some time,`destroy()` is invoked,then the connection will be closed.But the project is running some code that maybe periodically write to the database,that case a exception will be thrown.

Any solutions? And I want to know when the `servlet.destroy()` will be invoked.

Comment: You need to get a connection form the DataSource every time you need one, and use try-with-resources to close it as soon as you're done using it. Connections should not be shared between concurrent requests. Realize that your unique servlet instance serves the requests of all the users using your webapp. You also need to learn about transactions.

Comment: @JBNizet But I remember somebody said that build a connection is very expensive so we shouldn't build one and close it every that we execute a query?

Comment: That's why Java EE DataSources are backed up by a connection pool. Closing the connection just gives the connection back to the pool, where it can then be reused.

Answer (score 2):

That only works if you have one shared connection.

A better solution is to use the JNDI connection pooling capability built into your servlet engine. You want to use a connection in the smallest method scope possible and return it to the pool. You'll be able to serve more clients with a small connection pool that way.

Comment: Yes I made the connection a singleton now. So do you mean if I use the JNDI connection pooling,I won't worry about when to close the connection?Like there's no method like `connection.close()`,the pool will close them for me when I shut down the project?

Comment: Singleton can never scale.  You would be well advised to abandon that solution.

Comment: Ok I will change it that way~ And do you know when is `servlet.destroy()` invoked? I'm curious

Comment: When the server is shut down.  That's not the place to put anything.

Comment: why? Because I saw many people said that we should close the connection of database in the destroy() method.   And I printed some code when the destroy() method is invoked,but found out that even the server is not shut down destroy() is invoked either

Comment: @disinuo Having a single connection in a servlet means it will be shared by all requests to that servlet, even concurrent requests, which can lead to all kinds of nasty concurrency bugs. Therefor: use a data source (backed by a connection pool), get the connection when needed for the request, and close immediately when you are done. Closing the connection from a connection pooled data source will return that connection to the pool for re-use.

Comment: @disinuo, you can continue to cling to your first idea.  Nobody will stop you.  I'm sure you can find links to support whatever you'd like to do.  Every single application I've worked on has used the connection pools built into every Java EE app server and Spring.  Don't let that stop you - by all means, have a single connection and close it in the servlet destroy() method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel， @duffymo .Thank you~Really~.I said that not because I want to insist...Maybe my poor English got me misunderstood,I do realise the advantage of using a pool now.I just want to know why you said `servlet.destroy()` is not a right place to put anything,not want to argue...just a question out of curiosity...

Comment: [`Servlet.destroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#destroy--): in other words it is called when the container destroys the servlet; however a database connection should not be shared concurrently, and should be closed (or returned to the pool) as soon as you are done with it. So `destroy()` is not suitable, as it will only be called when the application is shutdown, or when the servlet container otherwise decides it is time to destroy it.